# Pilot Jobs, where to find one? How to land one?

Tags: commercial-aviation

I have just finished doing my commercial license in US and hold an FAA multi single IR and are converting to my Australian license, what are the job prospects like for a low time pilot in Australia i am not sure weather to go back to the US and train to get a CFI job over there. Just a little lost with my aviation career at the moment and in need of some guidance.
PS I am really not fussed who or where I fly, I just want to fly and get paid for it.

Comment: Get time.  Get time any way you can in anything eith wings.  Fly pipeline patrol, fly jumpers, fly for scheduled pt135 (e. Botique Air).  CFI work is a great way to rack up hours but I'd invest in a CFII and MEI if you take that route.

Comment: There are a reasonable amount of low-hour jobs in Australia, but for every one of those jobs there are dozens of pilots. I don't know how that compares to the US but I'm sure it's similar. Very few of those jobs are in the cities. Most people get their first job by driving out to the operators in the middle of nowhere, to prove their dedication, and stay there for a few weeks until they get an opportunity. Find something that sets you apart from the rest and sell that to anyone who will listen. Make friends with people with and without jobs, because you never know what might come up.